# Using the ternary operator with a lambda expression inside a foreach in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to lear how to properly use lambda expressions in C# and I got into this problem. I have an array of booleans defined like this:

```
public bool[] worldState = new bool[25];
```

Now, after giving values to it, I want to cycle thorugh it and simply print "T" when the bool is true, and "F" when it's false. I know how to do it with loops, but I wanted to do it with a one-liner, so I came up with this:

```
Array.ForEach(worldState, x => x? Console.WriteLine("T"): Console.WriteLine("F") );
```

This, however, won't work. Why? What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: You use a loop, that's how you do that.

Comment: A loop would be a lot easier to read and maintain, in this situation.

Comment: A ternary operator must return a value. But Console.WriteLine() doesn't.

Comment: I know a loop is better, it's just an exercise to learn about how lambda works, I'd never use that in production!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Array.ForEach(worldState, x =>  Console.WriteLine(x ? "T" : "F") );
```

The ternary function requires a value be returned, so in this case your T or F should be returned to the `WriteLine` method.

Personally, I think a `foreach` or `for` loop would be cleaner and more efficient.

```
foreach(bool bVal in Array) { Console.WriteLine(bVal ? "T" : "F"); }
```

or

```
for(i = 0; i < Array.Length; i ++) { Console.WriteLine(Array[i] ? "T" : "F"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax for an if-else in  `ForEach` would be:

```
Array.ForEach(worldState, x => { if(x) { Console.WriteLine("T"); } else { Console.WriteLine("F");}} );
```

The ternary operator `? :` requires expressions that return compatible values as the arguments.  `Console.WriteLine` is a `void` function and does not return a value.

Although I would note that a standard `foreach` loop is much easier to read and debug.  I would not recommend using `.ForEach()` for this type of operation.  In fact I wouldn't recommend it for *any* operation since it doesn't add any capability over the standard loop.

Comment: @clcto Thanks.  Fixed.  Another reason to not like multi-line lambdas :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Console.WriteLine()` doesn't return anything. From the Ternary operator documentation, emphasis mine:

> The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two **values**

and `Console.WriteLine()` does not return a value.

Just use an if statement:

```
Array.ForEach(worldState, x => { if(x) Console.WriteLine("T"); else Console.WriteLine("F"); } );
```

Another possibility is just return the string you want using the ternary operator:

```
Array.ForEach(worldState, x => Console.WriteLine( x ? "T" : "F" ) );
```